# How to get log file name and log directory in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

How to get the robot generated log file name and log directory.

I want to write a post process script, which can process the output XML file generated by robot.

Answer (score 3):

```
${LOG FILE}
```

Gives you absolute path to the log file.

```
${SUITE SOURCE}
```

Gives you absolute path to the suite file.

```
${OUTPUT DIR}
```

Gives you absolute path to the output directory.
http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html?r=2.8.4#automatic-variables

Comment: You saved my day! :)

Comment: Updated link: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#automatic-variables

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is to tell robot where you want the file to be, then you don't have to figure it out. Use the [output directory](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html?r=2.8.4#output-directory) command line option `--outputdir`. Unless you tell it where to put the output files, they will go into the current working directory.

If neither one of those works, you can capture the output of robot, and the last three lines will tell you the location of the output.xml, log.html and report.html files.